# How do I check the access rights of an app?

Tags: applications, security, mac-appstore, monterey

I am reading the following document: [About App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

It says:

> Access to any resource not explicitly requested in the project definition is rejected by the system at run time.

Is there a way to read the project definition of an app?

Comment: We strongly prefer one question per question, so I have edited this. Please ask your second question so it stands alone on expansion of sandbox. That may need more explanation of what you mean or what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entitlements requested by an app are stored in a structured file. Think of it like a shopping list.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements

When the application runs, the OS looks over the list, decides which to just grant and which need a pop up or some of their form or acceptance or pre-configuration before the entitlement request is logged and granted.

Checking these requires a dedicated tool or some experience with the command line to construct queries and filter data returned by the `codesign` and `security` commands.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/diagnosing_issues_with_entitlements